# Force to open my progressive web app in Chrome from WebView

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I developed a Progressive Web App (JS+HTML+CSS), which asks you to "Add to Homescreen" and "Permission for Push Notification" when the user opens it. The problem is that when the URL is opened from a WebView, for example Facebook WebView, the service worker not works.

So I want a way to force the user to open the URL in Chrome mobile. I try using `googlechrome://myurl.com` or `googlechromes://myurl.com` but not works, and I also try to create a link like `window.open('https://myurl.com, '_system')` but not works.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add more information like error logs or minimum working example?

Comment: I can't get error log from Facebook web view, but simply not shows the "Add to homescreen" banner nor the request for notifications permission.